# SizeForItemAtIndexPath: get items standard size

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I'm using the `sizeForItemAtIndexPath` function in a view controller that has two collection views.

How can I exclude one collection view in `sizeForItemAtIndexPath` function, or how could I get the original cell size without changing anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- to exclude one collection view

  ```
   func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        // to exclude one collection view
        if collectionView == collectionViewOne {}// first
       if collectionView.tag == number(you set before){}// second

       // to get the original cell size without changing anything
       //let yourSize = collectionViewLayout.itemSize
       //return collectionViewLayout.itemSize   // if you have set it globally, 
      /*
       But you can not get it, because itemSize is a property of UICollectionViewFlowLayout.

       And you can't cast collectionViewLayout to UICollectionViewFlowLayout Class which is kind of UICollectionViewLayout Class .

     Thats not how inheritance works.
    */    
  }
  ```
- to get the original cell size without changing anything

  ```
  let indexPath = IndexPath(item: number(you choose), section: number(you choose, 0 or 1))
  let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout() // you set
  // got the size
  // more generally, if you have set layout per item through delegate.
  let size = self.collectionView(collectionViewOne, layout: layout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath: indexPath)
  // or try this ,if you have configured globally
  let itemSize = layout.itemSize
  ```

Comment: I don't know why but I can't access layout.itemSize, it says 'Use of unresolved identifier "layout".'

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using storyboards, you can connect each collection view as an outlet to your view controller. E.g

```
@IBOutlet weak var collectionViewOne: UICollectionView!
@IBOutlet weak var collectionViewTwo: UICollectionView!

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
  if collectionView == collectionViewOne {
    // Do nothing, and set default size.
    return layout.itemSize
  } else {
    //Set size here along with other setup.
    return CGSize(width: 150, height: 150)
  }
}
```